# What is the difference between scope and block?

Tags: java

I saw a piece of code in a book, which is as follows:

```
x = 10;
if(x ==10) { // start new scope
int y = 20; // known only to this block
x = y * 2;
}
```

Are both, scope and block, the same?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

a scope is where you can refer to a variable.
a block defines a `block scope` a variable defined inside a block will be defined only inside that block and you can't reference it after the end of block.

so in this code if you try something like:

```
x = 10;
if(x ==10) { // start new scope
int y = 20; // known only to this block
x = y * 2;
}

y = 5; // error y is out of scope, not it is not defined
```

because what you have here is a local scope
other kinds of scope in java are `class scope` (for example), a member of a class has a class scope so it is accessible anywhere inside a class.

the basic rules for scope are:

1. The scope of a parameter declaration is the body of the method in
   which the declaration appears.
2. The scope of a local-variable declaration is from the point at which
   the declaration appears to the end of that block.
3. The scope of a local-variable declaration that appears in the
   initialization section of a for statement’s header is the body of
   the for statement and the other expressions in the header.
4. A method or field’s scope is the entire body of the class. This
   enables non-static methods of a class to use the fields and other
   methods of the class.

Answer (score 7):

From the [Java language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html):

[14.2. Blocks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.2):

> A block is a sequence of statements, local class declarations, and
>   local variable declaration statements within braces.

[6.3. Scope of a Declaration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3)

> The scope of a declaration is the region of the program within which
>   the entity declared by the declaration can be referred to using a
>   simple name, provided it is visible (§6.4.1).

In a block, you can *declare* variables. A scope defines the region, where you can *access* a declared variable by its simple name.

Answer (score 3):

when it comes to conditions and loops if you don't specify {} then immediate following statement is the only statement that will belong to particular condition or loop

e.g.

```
x = 10;
if(x ==10) 
{ 
int y = 20; 
x = y * 2;
}
both lines get executes only if condition returns TRUE

x = 10;
if(x ==10) 
int y = 20;
x = y * 2; // this is not belong to if condition. therefore it will execute anyway
```

Answer (score 3):

They are mostly the same.

A block is some code surrounded by { and }. A scope is the part of the program where a certain thing is visible. As far as I know, all blocks create scopes - anything defined in a block isn't visible outside the block. The converse is not true.

Here are some scopes without blocks:

```
for(int k = 0; k < 10; k++) { // k<10 and k++ are in a scope that includes k, but not in a block.
    System.out.println(k); // this is in a block (the {})
}

for(int k = 0; k < 10; k++) // k<10 and k++ are in a scope that includes k, as above
    System.out.println(k); // but there's no block!

class Test {
    // this is a scope but not a block. Not entirely sure about this one.
    int x = 2;
    int y = x + 1; // I can access x here, but not outside the class, so the class must be a scope.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As per definition of [Block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html)

> A block is a group of zero or more statements between balanced braces and can be used anywhere a single statement is allowed.

So

```
{   //block started

}    //block ended
```

**What ever the variables declared inside the block ,the scope restricted to that block.**

Is that making sense ??

Answer (score 3):

The oracle docs define block as

> A block is a group of zero or more statements between balanced braces
>   and can be used anywhere a single statement is allowed

@Mhd.Tahawi has already told what a scope is.

One thing I should point out,

```
switch(something){
    case somethin1:
        line1
        line2
        break;
    case someting2:
        line3
        line4
        break;
}
```

line{1,2,3,4} are within the same scope thus block because I did not begin and end each case with braces. Unlike python, indentation does not imply a block

Answer (score 3):

`Scope` refers to the `visibility of variables`. In other words, which parts of your program can see or use it. Normally, every variable has a global scope. Once defined, every part of your program can access a variable.

It is very useful to be able to limit a variable's scope to a single `function/block`. The variable will have a limited scope. This way, changes inside the `function/block` can't affect the main program in unexpected ways.

Answer (score 1):

From [Mozilla's A re-introduction to JavaScript (JS Tutorial)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript)

> An important difference between JavaScript and other languages like Java is that in JavaScript, blocks do not have scope; only functions have a scope. So if a variable is defined using var in a compound statement (for example inside an if control structure), it will be visible to the entire function. However, starting with ECMAScript 2015, let and const declarations allow you to create block-scoped variables.

Given the examples for var and how they differ from those for int and const, we can gather that, **in JavaScript**, a variable declared with var is visible outside of its immediate "scope," as we would typically use the word in other languages.

In the example given, something declared with var in a for-loop is available from **anywhere in the function**, both before and after the for-loop in which it was declared.

```
    // myVarVariable *is* visible out here

    for (var myVarVariable = 0; myVarVariable < 5; myVarVariable++) { 
      // myVarVariable is visible to the whole function 
    } 

    // myVarVariable *is* visible out here
```

This is in contrast to anything declared with let and const, which are limited to the **block** in which they are declared, in much the way variables are limited to the immediate scope of a single set of curly braces { } in other languages.

Moral of the story: be careful with var if you are used to other languages. It is much more powerful and visible than you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

For programming languages in general, the scope of a block (also known as block scope) is just one kind of scope; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Levels_of_scope.

Some languages, like Python, do not have blocks nor block scopes (but instead have function scopes, global scopes, etc.).