# Custom variable scope

Tags: java, variables, scope

Is it allowed to just place some curly braces without any if/for/etc statements to limit the variable scope?

An example:

```
public void myMethod()
{
    ...
    {
        int x;
        x = 5;
    }
    ...
}
```

I may want to do this, so I know for sure I won't access/change the variable outside the scope and that it will be destroyed beforehand

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: I did and it worked, but I was not sure is it allowed to do so or not. I also tried to search the web and found nothing about scopes like this. That's why I decided to ask

Comment: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241088/what-do-curly-braces-in-java-mean-by-themselves)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between scope and block?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575444/what-is-the-difference-between-scope-and-block)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's allowed. Just try and see for youtself

Answer (score 2):

The curly braces `{ .. }` limit the scope of variables to the block.
However, changes can be made to global variables falling into the scope of `{ .. }` block.

```
int x = -1;
double y = 5;
{
    x = 10;
    y = 100;
    char c = 'A';
}
System.out.println(x + " " + y); // 10 100.0
System.out.println(c); // Compile time error and out of scope

{
    c = 'B';  // Compile time error and out of scope
}
```