# Extracting a string from a separate statement

Tags: java

In my code, I create a string called `name` in my if else statement. However, I need to use the same string in a separate statement. This new statement creates a new file called (whatever the string in `name` is).

I get errors when I try and use the variable `name` in the new statement because it can't be identified. How can I fix this?

```
if (r == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
     String name = chooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
     System.out.println(name); //this is where I create string name
     name = name.replace(".asm", ".hack"); 
}
```

New Statement

```
try{
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("file.hack", "UTF-8"); //instead of using "file.hack", I need the new file to be called name
    writer.println(stringBuffer);
    writer.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
   // do something
}

Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("file.hack"));
while (input.hasNextLine())
{
  System.out.println(input.nextLine());
}
```

Comment: So, you want to read from a file even though the user did *not* approve in the file chooser? What should the file name be then, since the user has not chosen any file name?

Comment: Please check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575444/what-is-the-difference-between-scope-and-block. It might be helpful for you.

Comment: In fact, your question history suggests that you may be heading towards a question block. Let's try to avoid that please.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Define the variable first so that the variable scope is accessible across blocks.

```
String name = null;
if (r == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    name = chooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
}
try {
    if (name != null) {
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(name, "UTF-8");
        ...
    }
} catch
```

Or define the writer first and move the `try` into the `if`.

Comment: Please, add explanation why you moved `name` variable outside 'if' block.